# send goal to action server moveit2

Tags: rviz, moveit, ros-galactic

I initiate the demo of the default panda arm in rviz that comes with the tutorials:

`ros2 launch moveit_resources_panda_moveit_config demo.launch.py`

and now I want to send a pose in x,y,z world frame coordinates via action. I.e. it can be done c++ as described here:

https://moveit.picknik.ai/galactic/doc/examples/move_group_interface/move_group_interface_tutorial.html#

how can i just send a goal, like a pose, via `ros2 action send_goal` so that I can drive to it in rviz from terminal or python script for example?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you tried following the [tutorial for sending a goal to an action server without an action client?](http://wiki.ros.org/actionlib_tutorials/Tutorials/Calling%20Action%20Server%20without%20Action%20Client) It'd be easier for you to follow along with that tutorial and then come back with any specific issues you're having with it.

Comment: I actually did that tutorial already. I am also confident to write my own client for an action server. the problem i face is, I found no description which action i should send a goal and where in that message. following actions are available:

/execute_trajectory
/move_action
/panda_arm_controller/follow_joint_trajectory
/panda_hand_controller/gripper_cmd

I guess it is /move_group with .action type moveit_msgs/action/MoveGroup which is huge. In the turtlesim tutorial there are just a few parameters to send a goal to.